# How to extract multiple objects from JSON using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

There is a json file with multiple objects:

```
{
    "object1": {
        "property": "bar",
    },
    "object2": {
        "property": "foo",
    },
    "object3": {
        "property": "buzz"
    }
}
```

There are 3 classes as well, `Object1`, `Object2` and `Object3`, how can I extract all 3 as separate objects?

This obviously did not work:

```
Object1 = gson.fromJson(reader, Object1.class);
Object2 = gson.fromJson(reader, Object2.class);
Object3 = gson.fromJson(reader, Object3.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a wrapper class with these three properties

```
public class Wrapper {

 private Object1 object1;

 private Object2 object2;

 private Object3 object3;

  // getters and setters

}
```

And then use `gson.fromJson` to parse json into `Wrapper`

```
Wrapper wrapper = gson.fromJson(reader, Wrapper.class);
```

From `Wrapper` get all the required attributes

```
Object1 object1 = wrapper.getObject1();
Object2 object2 = wrapper.getObject2();
Object3 object3 = wrapper.getObject3();
```